# Why must Hamiltonian of a system be invariant under every operation of the relevant point group?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, hamiltonian

It is always claimed in any group theory books: "Hamiltonian of a system must be invariant under every operation of the relevant point group" or $RHR^{-1}=H$.

Suppose I have a Hamiltonian of H2 molecule. The Hamiltonian is quite complex, even if we ignore the kinetics of nuclei, and it still contains the electronic Hamiltonian. It will have kinetics of 2 electrons, nuclear potential, and the Coulomb repulsive potential.

$R$ is just a geometric operator acting on an object in 3D. In my opinion, it shouldn't act on a function. Therefore, what does "$RHR^{-1}=H$" exactly mean?

Even if it can act on a function, Hamiltonian in a molecule is already a many-electron problem, like $H\Psi(r_1,r_2)$. What will happen if $R\Psi(r_1,r_2)$? Why $RHR^{-1}\Psi(r_1,r_2)=H\Psi(r_1,r_2)$?

Comment: What is your definition of "the relevant point group" if not that it's a symmetry group, i.e. the Hamiltonian is invariant under it?

Comment: Like for molecule NH3. The relative point group is C3v.

Answer (score 0):

In physics generally (and especially this condensed-matter context), a symmetry (which includes all elements of the point group) is a property of the Hamiltonian. Specifically, it is a set of operations under which $H$ is invariant. So there's not some profound point here — it's just part of the definition of point group.

If you're asking why it's of the form $H = R^{\dagger} H R$, this is also the standard formulation of symmetries in quantum systems. Normally you'd think a symmetry operator should be something that commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$ (i.e., $R$ is a symmetry of $H$ if $[R,H]=0$). But if I take $H = R^{\dagger} H R$ and multiply from the left by $R$, I get $R H = H R \implies [H,R]=0$, as you'd expect. The reason commutation is important is that since $[H,R]=0$, the eigenstates of $H$ are also eigenstates of $R$, meaning that energy eigenstates have a definite eigenvalue (or charge) under the symmetry, so the symmetry is a good quantum number.